# Non-trivial analytics on timeseries

Tags: opentsdb

I was wondering, what is the mechanism on OpenTSDB to apply more complex functions than aggregations to data? For example if I wanted to calculate moving averages, how would I go for it? Ideally I would like a mechanism to run (through OpenTSDB) custom aggregators on HBase level ([example](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/mapreduce.example.html)), but I think this might not be very easy to implement. Alternatively something that runs on OpenTSDB-level would be nice. I think this might conceptually close to what [issue 546](https://github.com/OpenTSDB/opentsdb/issues/576)/[Pull 562](https://github.com/OpenTSDB/opentsdb/pull/562) talk about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a graphite-web app in front of the database and use its Functions: http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html

Comment: Thanks, I see the direction. When I said "aggregations" above I meant essentially the functions provided by aggregators (see "Available Aggregators" [here](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/query/aggregators.html). It would be I guess too costly to bring all those data out of HBase and OpenTSDB to Graphite.

Comment: Yes, graphite-web performs all the calculations acting as a client. To run custom functions directly in the database, it has to support this type of extension either via UDFs that you can reference in REST API by name or via SQL layer. Moving average is not really a good example of a complex function, the TSDBs need to support all kinds of MAs out of the box.

Comment: For MAs you mean that they are so common that they should be available out of the box, right? Yes - I just wanted to mention an example many people could relate to. I updated the question to reflect your previous comment. I understand the complexity of such requirement. It's just that if you run e.g. on 20 servers but you can't do distributed computation, you aren't, yet, that scalable nor distributed. If you need distributed comp'on you want to bring computation to the data - not the other way round.

Comment: I think bringing in custom code into HBase via co-processors is not the best idea. You'd have to take down regionservers anytime a user changes his code. If co-processors are not an option, than it's not scalable by your definition, because you'd have to aggregate all the rows on the client. Whether it's HTable instance in Java app or graphite-web via Java app - it's all the same. I still think that the proper way operationally to push down custom logic to the regionservers is via a SQL layer. For custom and complex - there's always Spark.

Comment: There is some relevant info in [chapter 4 of "Time Series Databases"](https://library.oreilly.com/book/0636920035435/time-series-databases-new-ways-to-store-and-access-data/toc)